# Unable to optimize queries - Bad design or Bad query or Both?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `questions` ( 
`question_id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`FK_quiz_id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL, 
`question_identify_text` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`), 
KEY `FK_quiz_id` (`FK_quiz_id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 

CREATE TABLE `question_multilingual` ( 
`question_multilingual_id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`FK_question_id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL, 
`FK_language_id` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL, 
`question` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`question_multilingual_id`), 
UNIQUE KEY `FK_question_id` (`FK_question_id`,`FK_language_id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 

CREATE TABLE `choices` ( 
`choice_id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`FK_question_id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL, 
`choice_identify_text` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`choice_id`), 
KEY `FK_question_id` (`FK_question_id`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 

CREATE TABLE `choice_multilingual` ( 
`choice_multilingual_id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`FK_choice_id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL, 
`FK_language_id` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL, 
`choice` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`choice_multilingual_id`), 
UNIQUE KEY `FK_choice_id` (`FK_choice_id`,`FK_language_id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

These are the table structures.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `questions` inner join question_multilingual on question_multilingual.FK_question_id = questions.question_id AND question_multilingual.FK_language_id = 1 INNER JOIN choices ON choices.FK_question_id = questions.question_id INNER JOIN choice_multilingual ON choice_multilingual.FK_choice_id = choices.choice_id AND choice_multilingual.FK_language_id = 1 WHERE FK_quiz_id = 1


1   SIMPLE  choice_multilingual NULL    ALL FK_choice_id    NULL    NULL    NULL    14  10.00   Using where 
1   SIMPLE  question_multilingual   NULL    ref FK_question_id,FK_language_id   FK_language_id  2   const   2   100.00  NULL    
1   SIMPLE  choices NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY,FK_question_id  PRIMARY 4   quizzes.choice_multilingual.FK_choice_id    1   14.29   Using where 
1   SIMPLE  questions   NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY,FK_quiz_id  PRIMARY 4   quizzes.question_multilingual.FK_question_id    1   100.00  Using where
```

I tried to change composite index, single index. Tried to add columns.
The results varies but not getting the optimized one whatever i do.

Comment: What did you expect to get? Why do you think this is wrong? The database engine knows a lot about the data and sometimes it’s better to not use indexes etc.

Comment: Results are not filtered properly. I tried to remove indexes. But not getting optimized result in the explain query

Comment: You’ll have to explain better what you mean. “Filtered properly” sounds like the query is wrong and has nothing to do with indexes. Input data, result, actual desired result etc would help a lot here. We can’t see what’s wrong with it.

Comment: Sir, database is designed for quiz. Questions and multiple choice answers. I have added the explain statement. question can have any number of choices. So choices contains the id of questions. When i do inner join of questions and choices, questions are filtered properly. But choices are not. I have already included all the show create table and query. I am just testing with dummy data like question1, choice1, choice2.